# css не видит html в новом приложение news

Tags: html, django, css3, jinja2

css не видит html в новом приложение news. При этом прекрасно видит код html в другом приложении main. [image: все мои файлы][image: html код в том приложении, которое не видит css][image: отсюда я с помощью Jinja шаблонизатора заимствую код][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: settings.py. local_settings.py, urls.py приложите

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. local_settings.py не создавал.

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что в **settings.py** (настройках проекта), имеются строки:

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
STATIC_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

А также, все файлы **templates** находятся в одной дирректории. Например, у Вас главный проект **main**. В нем есть папка **templates**, содержащая:

```
...
main
---templates
------main (файлы шаблона главного приложения)
------new (файлы шаблона приложения new)
...
------app (файлы шаблона app)
...
```

В противном случае, шаблоны приложения new не видят папки со стилями.